# SSRS Report Server 2008 Preview and Design do not match the published report (WYSIWYG Failure)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The preview of the SSRS report looks great and everything lines up.  There are four charts arranged in 2 by 2 and alongside of that on the right is a textbox and a rectangle below it with a table in it.  But when I go live, with the RDL file, there is a huge gap between the textbox and the rectangle with the list in it.  How do I align it?  This must be a problem others have overcome.  And this is not the first time I have seen align completely different from preview mode VS the published RDL.  Does it have something to do with the fact that it is compiled for a 2008 Report Server?
[image]

[image]

Comment: No report will look identical in a browser compared to the report designer/viewer. Exporting it will produce even more layout differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS aligns the objects with enough space automatically but there is a workaround.

If you put everything inside a rectangle (tables, textboxes, etc...) it will align like you placed it.